# Recurrence relation for number of bit strings of length n that contain two consecutive 1s

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm pulling my hair out over a review question for my final tomorrow.

> Find a recurrence relation (and its initial conditions) for the number of bit strings of length n that contain two consecutive 1s.

Here is my thought process/work, could someone please help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Knowing that a bit string of length 0 or 1 cannot contain two consecutive bits of any kind, and that only one bit string of length 2 (the string 11) can contain two consecutive ones, I have the initial conditions `a(0) = 0`, `a(1) = 0`, and `a(2) = 1`. I'm now trying to find a formula for the term `a(n+2)`.

I know there are three ways for a bit string of length `n + 2` to have two consecutive 1s:

- Condition `X`: Both `n + 1` and `n + 2` are 1. `count(X) = 2^n` because this still leaves `n` bits unaccounted for.
- Condition `Y`: Both `n` and `n + 1` are 1. `count(Y) = 2^n` for the same reason.
- Condition `Z`: The first `n` bits contain 11 somewhere. `count(Z) = 4 * a(n)` because adding 2 bits to the `a(n)` condition quadruples the number of possible strings.

Since these three conditions are not mutually exclusive,

```
a(n+2) count(X) + count(Y) + count(Z) - (count(X $\cup$ Y) + count(X $\cap$ Z) + count(Y $\cap$ Z)) + count($X \cap Y \cap Z)$
```

or

```
a(n+2) = 2^n + 2^n + 4 * a(n) - (2^(n-1) + a(n) + 2 * a(n-1)) + a(n-1)
```

This successfully proves the initial condition `a(2) = 1` and the next one - `a(3) = 3`. But when I plug in 4, I get 9. Listing out the possible strings by hand and circling the ones that satisfy the condition gives only 8. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The standard way is to find a recurrence for the number $b_n$ of bit strings that have **no two** consecutive $1$'s, then $a_n=2^n-b_n$.

Comment: In your approach, $count(Y\cap Z)$ looks wrong. For a direct approach you could count (1) the n-bit strings with two consecutive 1's that start with 0, (2) the n-bit strings with two consecutive 1's that start with 10, and (3) the n-bit strings with two consecutive 1's that start with 11.

Comment: This is in https://oeis.org/A008466, where the recurrence is in a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your count of $Y \cap Z$ requires that the two $1$'s in $Z$ be in the first $n-1$ bits.  For $n=4$ it does not include $001110$

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternate way of solving your question.

Let $a_n$ be the number of bit strings of length $n$ containing a pair of consecutive $1$'s.
In order to construct such a bit string, one could start with

- $0$ and follow with a string of length $(n-1)$ containing a pair of consecutive $1$'s
- $10$ and follow with a string of length $(n-2)$ containing a pair of consecutive $1$'s
- $11$ and follow with **any** string of length $(n-2)$

Since these three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaust the possibilities for how such a string might start, we can apply the **sum rule** and write down the following recurrence relation valid for all  $n \ge 2;$

$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + 2^{n-2}$

(Recall that there are $2^k$ bit strings on length $k$).

Now for the initial conditions:

- $a_0 = 0$
- $a_1 = 0$

Comment: The OP had "two consecutive $1$s", actually: you might want to re-align your notation. Also, the third should probably be "$00$ and follow with **any** string of length $(n-2)$". I could be wrong, so check it.

Comment: Hey, I fixed my error. Mind explaining what you mean by "re-align" my notation?

Comment: I meant "change it into the same as the OP". I probably should have said "align", but I'm not Paul Auster when it comes to English.

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle the case of $01$, followed by a string of length $(n-1)$ that starts with $1…$; which seems to be the crux of this problem, AFAICT?

Answer (score 4):

A perhaps less complicated way of solving the problem is to let $b_n$ be the number of length $n$ bit strings with **no** consecutive $1$'s. It is easy to show that
$$b_{n+2}=b_{n+1}+b_n.$$
Since $b_k=2^k-a_k$, substitution and a little simplification give
$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n+2^n.$$